# Trying to understand how an overloaded function is chosen

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, overload-resolution

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {

    template <class T> char test(int T::*)
    {
       std::cout << "Came to one\n";
       return 0;
    }

    template <class T> int test(...)
    {
       std::cout << "Came to two\n";
       return 0;
    }
}

struct A {};

int main()
{
   detail::test<A>(0);
   detail::test<int>(0);
}
```

When tested with g++ 4.8.2, it produces the following output:

```
Came to one
Came to two
```

My question: why is the first version of `detail::test` unambiguously chosen for the first call?

**Update**

In the absence of the first version of `details::test`, the code from `main` compiles fine. When it is there, the compiler thinks it's a better match for `detail::test<A>()` than the second one.

**Update 2**

After reading about *a pointer to member is well-formed even for incomplete types or without members of the designated type.*, I tried the following and it works.

```
struct A;

int main()
{
   detail::test<A>(0);
   detail::test<int>(0);
}
```

The C++11 standard has quite a few places to uncover concepts that I wouldn't have thought of.

Comment: What happens if you call passing 1 instead of 0? (0 is not a good test since it convert implicitly into a pointer as well)

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia, as you might have already guessed or found out, using `detail::test<A>(1);` ends up calling the second function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler goes through the Holy Trinity of Name Lookup, Argument Deduction and Overload Resolution. Name lookup finds two overloads for `test`, and the argument deduction of a pointer to member will fail for a non-class type, but not for incomplete types or missing members. Finally, out of the viable candidates, overload resolution picks the best match (the ellipsis conversion being the lowest rank).

---

There are three relevant Standard quotes here:

According to the Example in **8.3.3 Pointers to members [dcl.mptr]/2** a pointer to member is well-formed even for incomplete types or without members of the designated type.

According to **14.8.2 Template argument deduction [temp.deduct]/8**:

> If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type
>   deduction fails.

One of the many examples listed is:

> Attempting to create “pointer to member of T” when T is not a class
>   type.

Finally, according to **13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences [over.ics.rank]** the ellipsis `(...)` overload has the lowest rank of all implicit conversion sequences during overload resolution:

> 2 When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as
>   defined in 13.3.3.1)
>
> — a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is
>   a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence
>   or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and
>
> — a user-defined conversion
>   sequence (13.3.3.1.2) is a better conversion sequence than an ellipsis
>   conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.3).

Your first call `detail::test<A>(0);` has two viable candidates, but it picks the first overload because it is a better match . The second call `detail::test<int>(0);` gives a substition error on the first overload and therefore picks the second match.

Comment: @BЈовић When used at the beginning of a post, it means "Too long; don't read" :P

Comment: The part in the standard about *a pointer to member is well-formed even for incomplete types or without members of the designated type.* was a revelation. Thanks :)

Comment: @RSahu It was a surprise for me too! Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, the first overload gets picked over the second because it is a better fit as far as the [parameter conversion sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) are concerned - ellipsis conversion sequences rank last.